# Issues with Fusion Charts using Angular SSR

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, fusioncharts

I am trying to use FusionCharts with Angular 10 SSR but having a hard time making it work.

I found several threads about using isPlatformBrowser to only render the chart when the code is running on the front end, which works fine when I am coming to the page with the fusionchart modules.  However, when I try to refresh the page directly to the page/module with fusioncharts I get an error saying document is not defined.

```
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.isBrowser = true;
    }


ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: document is not defined
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

Below is what my module looks like for the module throwing the error on refresh.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NationalComponent } from './national/national.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { Snf360RoutingModule } from './snf360-routing.module';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [NationalComponent],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    CommonModule,
    Snf360RoutingModule,
  ],
})
export class Snf360Module { }
```

Inside of SharedModule I have my fusioncharts import.

```
import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import * as FusionTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion';
import * as charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
import * as maps from 'fusioncharts/maps/fusioncharts.usa';
import * as moremaps from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.maps';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material/dialog';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular-fusioncharts';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, charts, FusionTheme, maps, moremaps);
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    FusionChartsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    FusionChartsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MatDialogRef,
      useValue: {},
    },
    {
      provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
      useValue: {},
    },
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

I also found some info around including window and document object in server.ts with domino which I included, but I then get another error stating I'm trying to use property max of undefined.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'max' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'max' of undefined
```

Any ideas on how to resolve the issue?  I suspect something is wrong with my importing as it runs fine when I access the page from another page that doesn't import the shared module.

Thanks!

Comment: FusionCharts requires document or window object to render charts, for server-side rendering use FusionExport : https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/exporting-charts/using-fusionexport/overview

Comment: also make sure angular-fusioncharts is 3.0.4

Comment: I am using angular-fusioncharts v3.0.4, which allows the chart to render when coming from another route.  I think this may be more related to module imports on top of fusioncharts issues.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Server side rendering you need to code being carefully with your code. Because some things changes when you code run in the server. Some of those things are the realted browser objects such as Document, window, etc and some functions such as SetTimeout and SetInterval. Those objects and functions does not exist in the server. So you need to avoid executon of some code when you are in the server and this is an example

```
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) { ... }

ngOnInit() {
  if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
     // Client only code.
     ...
  }
  if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
    // Server only code.
    ...
  }
}
```

Also, checked the package in package.json file -

```
"@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
"@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
```